# Better way to have foreach loop iteration tracking integer value incrementing

Tags: c#

is there any better way of this code

```
var dictionary= new Dictionary<int,object>();

int x=0;

foreach( var item in SomeCollection)
{
    x++;
    dictionary.Add(x,item);
}
```

Whats the best practice ?  Can we avoid declaring int x=0; and get the current iteration value ??

Comment: you could use a for loop `for (int x = 0; x < SomeCollection.Length, x++)`

Comment: The duplicate is a `Dictionary<string, int>` but the same patterns apply.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly a `for` loop.  Optionally you could use LINQ:

```
int temp = 0;
var dict = SomeCollection.ToDictionary(_ => ++temp, item => item);
```